# Container is not showing the full grid

Tags: html, css

So i was just finishing building my first full site (with html and css), and in the video it was missing a portfolio page, i created one watching a video of a cool image grid i founded, but the grid keeps getting cut off. (Thats not the full html code, i deleted the other pages that are correct) [Full image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILQso.png)

```css
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  background-color: #040404;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  background: transparent;
} 

body::before {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  background: #040404 url("../../assets/img/background.jpg") top right no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: -1;
}

a {
  color: #18d26e;
}

a:hover {
  color: #35e888;
  text-decoration: none;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
}

  
#header {
  transition: ease-in-out 0.3s;
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 997;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#header * {
  transition: ease-in-out 0.3s;
}

#header h1 {
  font-size: 48px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

#header h1 a, #header h1 a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1;
  display: inline-block;
}

#header h2 {
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}

#header h2 span {
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #18d26e;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
}

#header img {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#header .social-links {
  margin-top: 40px;
  display: flex;
}

#header .social-links a {
  font-size: 16px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1;
  margin-right: 8px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

#header .social-links a:hover {
  background: #18d26e;
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
  #header h1 {
    font-size: 36px;
  }
  #header h2 {
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 30px;
  }
  #header .social-links {
    margin-top: 15px;
  }
  #header .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }
}
.nav-menu {
  margin-top: -450px;
  margin-left: 70%;
}

.nav-menu ul {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-menu li + li {
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.nav-menu a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.nav-menu a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: -4px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #18d26e;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 0px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.nav-menu a:hover:before, .nav-menu li:hover > a:before, .nav-menu .active > a:before {
  visibility: visible;
  width: 25px;
}

.nav-menu a:hover, .nav-menu .active > a, .nav-menu li:hover > a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}


.mobile-nav-toggle {
  position: fixed;
  right: 15px;
  top: 15px;
  z-index: 9998;
  border: 0;
  background: none;
  font-size: 24px;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  outline: none !important;
  line-height: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: right;
}

.mobile-nav-toggle i {
  color: #fff;
}

.mobile-nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 55px;
  right: 15px;
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  z-index: 9999;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: ease-in-out 0.2s;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12);
}

.mobile-nav * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.mobile-nav a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  outline: none;
}

.mobile-nav a:hover, .mobile-nav .active > a, .mobile-nav li:hover > a {
  color: #18d26e;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.mobile-nav-overly {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9997;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  background: rgba(9, 9, 9, 0.6);
  overflow: hidden;
  display: none;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.2s;
}

.mobile-nav-active {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.mobile-nav-active .mobile-nav {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.mobile-nav-active .mobile-nav-toggle i {
  color: #fff;
}

/* Header Top */
#header.header-top {
  height: 80px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

#header.header-top .social-links, #header.header-top h2 {
  display: none;
}

#header.header-top h1 {
  margin-right: auto;
  font-size: 36px;
}

#header.header-top .container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#header.header-top .nav-menu {
  margin: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #header.header-top {
    height: 60px;
  }
  #header.header-top h1 {
    font-size: 26px;
  }
}
section {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 140px;
  bottom: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.4s;
  z-index: 2;
}

section.section-show {
  top: 100px;
  bottom: auto;
  opacity: 1;
  padding-bottom: 45px;
}

section .container {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  padding: 30px;
}

@media (max-width: 1080px) {
  section {
    top: 120px;
  }
  section.section-show {
    top: 80px;
  }
}

.section-title h2 {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1px;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #aaaaaa;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

.section-title h2::after {
  content: "";
  width: 120px;
  height: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #4ceb95;
  margin: 4px 10px;
}

.section-title p {
  margin: 0;
  margin: -15px 0 15px 0;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
}

.about-me .content h3 {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 26px;
  color: #18d26e;
}

.about-me .content ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.about-me .content ul li {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.about-me .content ul i {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-right: 2px;
  color: #18d26e;
}

.about-me .content p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.counts {
  padding: 70px 0 60px;
}

.counts .count-box {
  padding: 30px 30px 25px 30px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.08);
}

.counts .count-box i {
  position: absolute;
  top: -25px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  font-size: 24px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  padding: 12px;
  color: #18d26e;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.counts .count-box span {
  font-size: 36px;
  display: block;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
}

.counts .count-box p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.skills .progress {
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  background: none;
}

.skills .progress .skill {
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 0 0 6px 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
}

.skills .progress .skill .val {
  float: right;
  font-style: normal;
}

.skills .progress-bar-wrap {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
}

.skills .progress-bar {
  width: 1px;
  height: 10px;
  transition: .9s;
  background-color: #18d26e;
}

.interests .icon-box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.08);
  transition: ease-in-out 0.3s;
}

.interests .icon-box i {
  font-size: 32px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  line-height: 1;
}

.interests .icon-box h3 {
  font-weight: 700;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
}

.interests .icon-box:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12);
}

.testimonials .testimonial-item {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  min-height: 320px;
}

.testimonials .testimonial-item .testimonial-img {
  width: 90px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: -40px 0 0 40px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  border: 6px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12);
}

.testimonials .testimonial-item h3 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 10px 0 5px 45px;
  color: #fff;
}

.testimonials .testimonial-item h4 {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #999;
  margin: 0 0 0 45px;
}

.testimonials .testimonial-item .quote-icon-left, .testimonials .testimonial-item .quote-icon-right {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
  font-size: 26px;
}

.testimonials .testimonial-item .quote-icon-left {
  display: inline-block;
  left: -5px;
  position: relative;
}

.testimonials .testimonial-item .quote-icon-right {
  display: inline-block;
  right: -5px;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
}

.testimonials .testimonial-item p {
  font-style: italic;
  margin: 0 15px 0 15px;
  padding: 20px 20px 60px 20px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 6px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.testimonials .owl-nav, .testimonials .owl-dots {
  margin-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.testimonials .owl-dot {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) !important;
}

.testimonials .owl-dot.active {
  background-color: #18d26e !important;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .testimonials {
    margin: 30px 10px;
  }
}
.honeycomb
{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  transform: translateY(80px);
}

.honeycomb-cell
{
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  flex: 0 1 250px;
  max-width: 250px;
  height: 137.5px;
  margin: 65.4px 12.5px 25px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0.5em;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.honeycomb-cell_img
{
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}
.honeycomb-cell_title
{
  height: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;
  word-break: break-word;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.75em;
  transition: opacity 350ms;
}
.honeycomb-cell_title > small
{
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-top: 0.25em;
}
.honeycomb-cell::before,
.honeycomb-cell::after
{
  content: '';
}
.honeycomb-cell::before,
.honeycomb-cell::after,
.honeycomb-cell_img
{
  top: -50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0% 75%, 0% 25%);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0% 75%, 0% 25%);
  z-index: -1;
}
.honeycomb-cell::before
{
  background: #fff;
  transform: scale(1.055);
}
.honeycomb-cell::after
{
  background: #111111;
  opacity: 0.7;
  transition: opacity 350ms;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 350ms;
}
.honeycomb-cell:hover
.honeycomb-cell_title
{
  opacity: 0;
}
.honeycomb-cell:hover
.honeycomb-cell_img
{
  filter: grayscale(0%);
}
.honeycomb-cell:hover::before
{
  background: #18d26e;
}
.honeycomb-cell:hover::after
{
  opacity: 0;
}
.honeycomb_Hidden
{
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 250px;
  margin: 0 12.5px;
}

@media (max-width: 550px) 
{
  .honeycomb-cell 
  {
    margin: 81.25px 25px;
  }
}


@media (min-width: 550px) and (max-width: 1080px) 
{
  .honeycomb-cell:nth-child(3n) 
  {
    margin-right: calc(50% - 125px);
    margin-left: calc(50% - 125px);
  }

  .honeycomb_Hidden:nth-child(3n + 5) 
  {
    display: block;
  }
}


@media (min-width: 825px) and (max-width: 1100px) {
 
  .honeycomb-cell:nth-child(5n + 4) 
  {
    margin-left: calc(50% - 275px);
  }

  .honeycomb-cell:nth-child(5n + 5) 
  {
    margin-right: calc(50% - 275px);
  }

  .honeycomb_Hidden:nth-child(5n), 
  .honeycomb_Hidden:nth-child(5n + 3) 
  {
    display: block;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1100px) 
{
  .honeycomb-cell:nth-child(7n + 5) {
    margin-left: calc(50% - 400px);
  }

  .honeycomb-cell:nth-child(7n + 7), 
  .honeycomb-cell:nth-child(7n + 5):nth-last-child(2) 
  {
    margin-right: calc(50% - 400px);
  }

  .honeycomb_Hidden:nth-child(7n + 7), 
  .honeycomb_Hidden:nth-child(7n + 9), 
  .honeycomb_Hidden:nth-child(7n + 11) 
  {
    display: block;
  }
}

.services .icon-box {
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.1);
  padding: 80px 20px;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s;
}

.services .icon-box .icon {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  background: #18d26e;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all .3s ease-out 0s;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.services .icon-box .icon i {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 28px;
}

.services .icon-box .icon::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: -8px;
  top: -8px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all .3s ease-out 0s;
  transform: translateZ(-1px);
}

.services .icon-box h4 {
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.services .icon-box h4 a {
  color: #fff;
}

.services .icon-box p {
  line-height: 24px;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.services .icon-box:hover {
  background: #18d26e;
  border-color: #18d26e;
}

.services .icon-box:hover .icon {
  background: #fff;
}

.services .icon-box:hover .icon i {
  color: #b2c2b9;
}

.services .icon-box:hover .icon::before {
  background: #35e888;
}

.services .icon-box:hover h4 a, .services .icon-box:hover p {
  color: #fff;
}


@-webkit-keyframes animate-loading {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes animate-loading {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}


.credits {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 999999;
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
  .credits {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  }
}

.credits a {
  color: #18d26e;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.credits a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">

  <title>Rodrigo C. Programmer</title>
  <meta content="" name="description">
  <meta content="" name="keywords">

  <!-- Favicons -->
  <link href="assets/img/favicon/favicon.ico" rel="icon">

  <!-- Google Fonts -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i|Raleway:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i|Poppins:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Vendor CSS Files -->
  <link href="assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/vendor/icofont/icofont.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/vendor/remixicon/remixicon.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/vendor/owl.carousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/vendor/boxicons/css/boxicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/vendor/venobox/venobox.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Template Main CSS File -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">

</head>

<body>

  <!-- ======= Header ======= -->
  <header id="header" class="header-tops">
    <div class="container">

      <h1><a href="index.html">Rodrigo Carrard</a></h1>
      <h2>Apenas um <span>Programador</span> do Brasil</h2>
      <div class="social-links">
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/rodrigocarrard/" target="_blank" class="instagram"><i class="icofont-instagram"></i></a>
      </div>
      <nav class="nav-menu d-none d-lg-block">
        <ul>
          <li class="active"><a href="#header">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav><!-- .nav-menu -->

    

    </div>
  </header><!-- End Header -->

  <!-- ======= Portfolio Section ====== -->
  <section id="portfolio" class="portfolio">
    <div class="container">

      <div class="section-title">
        <h2>Portfolio</h2>
        <p>Meus projetos</p>
      </div>

      <ul class="honeycomb">
        <li class="honeycomb-cell">
            <img class="honeycomb-cell_img" src="assets/img/LogoRc.png">
            <div class="honeycomb-cell_title"><a href="http://localhost/portfolio/index.html">R.C Portfolio</a></div>
        </li>
        <li class="honeycomb-cell">
            <img class="honeycomb-cell_img" src="assets/img/clientes/diceshield.png">
            <div class="honeycomb-cell_title"><a href="http://localhost/partybuddy">Party Buddy</a></div>
        </li>
        <li class="honeycomb-cell honeycomb_Hidden">
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
  </section>

 
  <!-- ======= Services Section ======= -->
  <section id="services" class="services">
    <div class="container">

      <div class="section-title">
        <h2>Services</h2>
        <p>Meus serviços</p>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 d-flex align-items-stretch">
          <div class="icon-box">
            <div class="icon"><i class="bx bxl-dribbble"></i></div>
            <h4><a href="">Desenvolvimento de site</a></h4>
            <p>Farei seu site do utilizando Html / Css / JavaScript / Php </p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 d-flex align-items-stretch mt-4 mt-md-0">
          <div class="icon-box">
            <div class="icon"><i class="bx bx-file"></i></div>
            <h4><a href="">Wordpress Site</a></h4>
            <p>Desenvolverei seu site profissional ultilizando o Wordpress</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 d-flex align-items-stretch mt-4 mt-lg-0">
          <div class="icon-box">
            <div class="icon"><i class="bx bx-tachometer"></i></div>
            <h4><a href="">Criação de aplicativos Mobile</a></h4>
            <p>Desenvolverei seu aplicativo mobile com base no seu pedido</p>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
  </section><!-- End Services Section -->
 

  <!-- ======= Contact Section ======= -->
  <section id="contact" class="contact">
    <div class="container">

      <div class="section-title">
        <h2>Contact</h2>
        <p>Meu contato</p>
      </div>

      <div class="row mt-2">

        <div class="col-md-6 d-flex align-items-stretch">
          <div class="info-box">
            <i class="bx bx-map"></i>
            <h3>Endereço</h3>
            <p>Itapema, Meia Praia, SC, Brasil</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 mt-4 mt-md-0 d-flex align-items-stretch">
          <div class="info-box">
            <i class="bx bx-share-alt"></i>
            <h3>Social Profiles</h3>
            <div class="social-links">
              <a href="https://www.instagram.com/rodrigocarrard/" target="_blank" class="instagram"><i class="icofont-instagram"></i></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 mt-4 d-flex align-items-stretch">
          <div class="info-box">
            <i class="bx bx-envelope"></i>
            <h3>Meu email</h3>
            <p>rodrigocarrard.pessoal@gmail.com</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 mt-4 d-flex align-items-stretch">
          <div class="info-box">
            <i class="bx bx-phone-call"></i>
            <h3>Telefone</h3>
            <p>Ainda não disponivel</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <form action="forms/contact.php" method="post" role="form" class="php-email-form mt-4">
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 4 chars" />
            <div class="validate"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" data-rule="email" data-msg="Please enter a valid email" />
            <div class="validate"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 8 chars of subject" />
          <div class="validate"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="5" data-rule="required" data-msg="Please write something for us" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
          <div class="validate"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
          <div class="loading">Loading</div>
          <div class="error-message"></div>
          <div class="sent-message">Your message has been sent. Thank you!</div>
        </div>
        <div class="text-center"><button type="submit">Send Message</button></div>
      </form>

    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- Vendor JS Files -->
  <script src="assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/vendor/jquery.easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/vendor/php-email-form/validate.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/vendor/waypoints/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/vendor/counterup/counterup.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/vendor/owl.carousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/vendor/isotope-layout/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/vendor/venobox/venobox.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Template Main JS File -->
  <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please tag Bootstrap and your version.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace this for your body styling

```css
body{
position:relative;
z-index:1;
color:#070707;
            
}
body::before{
content:"";
width:100vw;
height:100vh;
background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILQso.png");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
background-position:center center;
background-attachment:fixed;
position:absolute;
z-index:-1;
}
```

> I have positioned the `body` relative  and `body::before` pseudo element position `absolute` and made it go at the back of the body using `z-index` for it to appear as a background. Try out this implemetation. For the Image I have used an online image url